# Can't replace filtered rows/constants

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, spreadsheet

I have a table which has Questions (Column A) and then multiple possible answers associated with each question (Column B). This means that for most questions there are a few blank rows in Column A as the question is at the top and then the multiple possible associated answers are to the right in Column B.

I want to assign each question a number (ID). So I tried filtering out the blanks and then pasting in the ID's. It didn't work. Then I found out about "visible cells only" and constants. Yet pasting into these still didn't work. What I thought would be a relatively simple task is driving me crazy. How can I paste in some values whilst ignoring the blanks in between?

Comment: "...there are a few blank rows in Row A..." How can you have a few blank rows in a single row? Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1505308/edit) to remove the confusion between rows and columns

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad My mistake, I've corrected it now.

Comment: There is some funkiness with copying and pasting data when you have hidden/filtered rows. I can't explain why sometimes it works as expected and other times it doesn't. Either do this manually, or create a formula to populate an id based on the question.

Comment: @MikeS,, better [Edit] the post & share sample data with us since current one is quite confusing !!

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem?

Comment: I managed to get what I wanted just by doing the same thing on google sheets instead and then pasting the values back into my excel spreadsheet. Basically the "select visible only" feature doesn't work when trying to change multiple cells at once. It will still change all the cells in the hidden rows in between at the same time as the ones you have selected.